# How to loop through a list of loans in Python to generate amortization schedule?

Tags: python, loops, amortized-analysis, amortization

I'm new to Python and am trying to generate an amortization schedule for a list of 400 loans. The final result only contains the loan_id and remaining_balance for each month end till the loan is paid off.

I found a [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YRSK.png) on amortize function and **need help on how to loop through my list of loans.**

My loan list looks like this:

[image]

Below is the code I currently using:

```
def amortize(loan_id, principal, remaining_balance, interest_rate, years, annual_payments=12, start_date=date.today()):

    pmt = -round(np.pmt(interest_rate/annual_payments, years*annual_payments, principal), 2)
    # initialize the variables to keep track of the periods and running balances
    p = 1
    beg_balance = remaining_balance
    end_balance = remaining_balance

    while end_balance > 0:

        # Recalculate the interest based on the current balance
        interest = round(((interest_rate/annual_payments) * beg_balance), 2)

        # Determine payment based on whether or not this period will pay off the loan
        pmt = min(pmt, beg_balance + interest)
        principal = pmt - interest

        # Ensure additional payment gets adjusted if the loan is being paid off
        end_balance = beg_balance - principal 

        yield OrderedDict([('Load ID', loan_id),
                           ('Month',start_date),
                           ('Period', p),
                           ('Begin Balance', beg_balance),
                           ('Payment', pmt),
                           ('Principal', principal),
                           ('Interest', interest),
                           ('End Balance', end_balance)])

        # Increment the counter, balance and date
        p += 1
        start_date += relativedelta(months=1)
        beg_balance = end_balance
```

I only know how to apply the amortize function to selected row but how can I write a loop to all my lists?
(list is the name of my loan dataframe)

```
amo_schedule = pd.DataFrame(amortize(list['id'][0],
                                     list['origination'][0],
                                     list['remaining_balance'][0],
                                     list['interest'][0]/100,
                                     list['term'][0],
                                     start_date=date(2020,11,1)))
```

I got an error msg with the following code when I removed the index.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(amortize(list['id'],
                    list['origination'],
                    list['remaining_balance'],
                   list['interest'],
                   list['term'],
                    start_date=date(2020,11,1)))
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-314-11e01c7c284f> in <module>
----> 1 test = pd.DataFrame(amortize(list['id'],
      2                     list['origination'],
      3                     list['remaining_balance'],
      4                    list['interest'],
      5                    list['term'],

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    500         elif isinstance(data, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
    501             if not isinstance(data, (abc.Sequence, ExtensionArray)):
--> 502                 data = list(data)
    503             if len(data) > 0:
    504                 if is_dataclass(data[0]):

<ipython-input-281-f6ccf21b26cb> in amortize(loan_id, principal, remaining_balance, interest_rate, years, annual_payments, start_date)
      7     end_balance = remaining_balance
      8 
----> 9     while end_balance > 0:
     10 
     11         # Recalculate the interest based on the current balance

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  thx for your comment, I added one more script on apply function in a specific column but still couldn't get it how to apply the function to all my rows.

Comment: Please post the error as text instead of a screenshot. You can use triple-backticks to preserver formatting just like you do with code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks

Comment: The error tells you exactly what your options are: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." Work your way backwards to find what `Series` this refers to. In this case, it looks like `end_balance > 0` is the culprit. Here you compare an entire series, not just a single number.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Hi thanks for the feedback, but I resolved this by creating a new empty dataframe with the defined columns and append the amortize function into it. `amo_schedule_final =  pd.DataFrame( columns=['Loan ID', 'Month', 'Period', 'Begin Balance', 'Payment', 'Principal','Interest','End Balance'])
for index in range(0,493):
    amo_schedule_final = amo_schedule_final.append(pd.DataFrame(amortize(list['id'][index],
                                     list['origination'][index],
                                     ...)))`

Comment: Feel free to post an answer below. Post as an answer instead of a comment allows you to provide more detail because the number of characters aren't limited and to format your code so that future visitors can read it better.